# React / Axios prevent fetch API call get multiple times

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am new to programming world and reactjs.

I have created a react app. In my homepage component, the purpose of it is to fetch the data from the server and then pass those data to the corresponding components.

I use the jsonplaceholder as my fake api shown in the codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-antonelli-ju56k

When I console.log the data, I get 2 results:

```
[]
[]
-> actual data get back
-> actual data get back
```

How can I prevent those empty fetching?? What's the best way to handle this?

Here is my jsx code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Homepage.css";

import Hero from "../components/Hero/Hero";
import ImageGallery from "../components/ImageGallery/ImageGallery";

import Axios from "axios";

export class Homepage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ data: res.data });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const data = this.state;
    console.log(data, "hi");
    return (
      <>
        <Hero jsondata={data} />
        <ImageGallery jsondata={data} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: if your goal is to not render the components in render till the time data is not fetched, then you should use conditional rendering. e.g. render the components only if the data is present.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Following the conditional rendering, I've modified my code in the codesandbox. [codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-antonelli-ju56k]. but another problem is occurred. My child components receive undefined after passing from parent components. is it the correct way to pass data like that?

Comment: This is because you are not using the right state variable. I can see three different states to keep the data fetched from the api. The fetched data is set in `aftherFetchingData` after Axios call, render is using `jsonData` and state is initialised with `data` in the constructor. 

 Please keep it same across the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. Those are not empty fetching but are the result of a `console.log` before `data` are actually retrieved. According to the React lifecycle of a component: the component is mount, `render` method firstly executed (that's why you get an empty `console.log`). After this the `componentDidMount` method trigger, starting the code to fetch you're data. You can learn more about React lifecycle here: [React lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

This mechanism ensure that you're view is loaded in the page, showing something to the user, while data are asynchronously retrieved. Once the data arrived the component will be rerendered with data.

You may however decide to retrieve data in a synchronous way blocking first component rendering until data are fully available but that would be an anti-pattern.

If you instead want to show something just after data arrived you may consider *conditional rendering*. That is render the component just if some conditions occur. Here the official doc [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

The mechanism to pass data from parent component to child component is that of `props`.

Define child as:

```
function Child(props) {
    console.log(props.myData)
    console.log(props.prop2)
}
```

And then:

```
<Parent>
    <Child myData={data} prop2={"just another prop"}></Child>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've modified my code in the codesandbox. [https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-antonelli-ju56k]. but another problem is occurred. My child components receive undefined after passing from parent components. is it the correct way to pass data like that?

Comment: You were almost there, I modified you're sandbox and updated this answer.

Comment: Pay attention that to destructure object you need variables to have same name. `this.state = { data: [], isLoading : false }` and `const {data, isLoading} = this.state`

Comment: Here the working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-keldysh-rq27v

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a problem to be worry about and it's completely normal in react js .
The component renders itself at first so the first console.log is for that . Then when you make an axios call on componentDidMount lifecycle method , It re-renders itself again .

It's react js nature to re-render when the state or props change . You may want to use react's PureComponent . You can find all the documentation on that in [react's own documenttaion website](https://reactjs.org)